# Grails script and passing parameters using Groovy CLIBuilder?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have created a very simple script and would like to pass arguments to the script.

like:

```
grails> helloworld -n Howdy
grails> helloworld -name Howdy
```

with the script:

```
target(main: 'Hello World') {
    def cli = new CliBuilder()
    cli.with
            {
                h(longOpt: 'help', 'Help - Usage Information')
                n(longOpt: 'name', 'Name to say hello to', args: 1, required: true)
            }
    def opt = cli.parse(args)
    if (!opt) return
    if (opt.h) cli.usage()
    println "Hello ${opt.n}"
}
```

I seem to fail in every attempt that i do. The script keeps complain about the -n option being not present.

When i debug the script the value op the args parameters looks like the values are rearranged.

When calling the script with :

```
grails> helloworld -n Howdy
```

the value of args inside the script is: **Howdy -n**

What am i missing here of doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running your code through `grails` shell. I've converted your code to `CLI.groovy` like this:

```
class CLI{
 public static void main(String [] args){
     def cli = new CliBuilder()
     cli.with
            {
                h(longOpt: 'help', 'Help - Usage Information')
                n(longOpt: 'name', 'Name to say hello to', args: 1, required: true)
             }
      def opt = cli.parse(args)
      if (!opt) return
      if (opt.h) cli.usage()
      println "Hello ${opt.n}"
      }
 }
```

After that I'm using `groovy` command to run it from linux shell like that:

```
 archer@capitan $ groovy CLI -n Daddy
```

It outputs:

```
 archer@capitan $ groovy CLI -n Daddy
 Hello Daddy
```

So it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! But i need this inside the grails shell, i am trying to use the parameters for some grails script i want to adjust.

Comment: I'm not sure you can pass parameters from within grails shell

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google search for `site:github.com grailsScript CliBuilder` and came across:

https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-cxf/blob/master/scripts/WsdlToJava.groovy

That gave me the hint that the `args` variable needs to be formatted. Unfortunately it mutates `-n Howdy` into `Howdy\n-n` (not sure why the order is rearranged or the newline character is added).

The github page above has a `doSplit()` method to handle some of this, but it keeps the rearranged order. The best thing I've found is to remove the space between `-n` and `Howdy`, which will work with CliBuilder.

The following is what I have working:

```
target(main: 'Hello World') {
    def cli = new CliBuilder()
    cli.with
            {
                h(longOpt: 'help', 'Help - Usage Information')
                n(longOpt: 'name', 'Name to say hello to', args: 1, required: true)
            }
    def ops = doSplit(args)
    def opt = cli.parse(ops)
    if (!opt) return
    if (opt.h) cli.usage()
    println "Hello ${opt.n}"
}

private doSplit(String string){
    string.split(/(\n|[ ]|=)/).collect{ it.trim() }.findResults  { it && it != '' ? it : null }
}
```

Run this with: `helloworld -nHowdy`